# Building sphinx documents inside Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, python-sphinx

I have a Flask project that runs inside a Docker container. I have managed to build my application and run it successfully. However, I would like to also build the sphinx documentation, so its static files can be served. The documentation is normally built using `make html` in the `docs/` file. I've found a docker source for sphinx, and have set up a `docker-compose` config that runs successfully, however, I am not able to pass the `make html` command to sphinx -- I believe because I am running the command a level up, since `make html` needs to be run from within `docs/` and not from within the base directory.

I get the following error when I try to build the sphinx documentation:

```
docker-compose run --rm sphinx make html
Starting web_project
Pulling sphinx (nickjer/docker-sphinx:latest)...
latest: Pulling from nickjer/docker-sphinx
c62795f78da9: Pull complete
d4fceeeb758e: Pull complete
5c9125a401ae: Pull complete
0062f774e994: Pull complete
6b33fd031fac: Pull complete
aac5b231ab1e: Pull complete
97be0ae484bc: Pull complete
ec7c8cca5e46: Pull complete
82cc981959eb: Pull complete
151a33a826a1: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:8125ca919069235278a5da631c002926cc57d741fa041b59c758183ebd48121f
Status: Downloaded newer image for nickjer/docker-sphinx:latest
make: *** No rule to make target 'html'.  Stop.
```

My project has the following directory structure

```
docs/
web/
    Dockerfile
    run.py
    requirements.txt
    ....
docker-compose.yml
README.md
```

And the following docker-compose configuration

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        restart: always
        build: ./web
        ports:
            - "7000:7000"
        environment:
            DEBUG: 'true'
        command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :7000 run:app

    sphinx:
        image: "nickjer/docker-sphinx"
        volumes:
            - "${PWD}:/docs"
        user: "1000:1000"
        depends_on:
            - web
```

How do I build my sphinx documentation within the Docker container? Do I need to add another Dockerconfig file to my `docs` module?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe because I am running the command a level up, since make html
>   needs to be run from within docs/ and not from within the base
>   directory.

To test this theory, could you try something like this command?

`docker-compose run --rm sphinx bash -c "cd docs; make html"`

or possibly

`docker-compose exec sphinx bash -c "cd docs; make html"`

Comment: Hm looks like my hypothesis is incorrect -- I get the following when I run the first docker-compose command: `bash: line 0: cd: docs: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'html'.  Stop.` . So I'd guess that I am in fact in `/docs` ? Not sure why I can't `make` my target within the docker container, though, when the same `make html` command works sans docker. Any thoughts on additional ways to troubleshoot the docker container? Thanks!

Comment: I'm also getting same result: `No rule to make target 'html'. Stop.` Looks like it's probably some missing configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I had success with the following to build and deploy my sphinx docs for static read by the Flask app.

```
WORKDIR /pathapp/app
ENV PYTHON /pathapp/app
RUN python  /pathapp/app/setup.py build_sphinx -b html
RUN python /pathapp/app/scripts/script_to_copy_build_sphinx_html_to_docs.py
```

The move script is just a simple copy directory.